# Java negative exponential operator?

Tags: java, operators, exponential, exponent

How can I create an exponential operator class which supports negative numbers?

My code:

```
public void execOP(float val1, float val2) {
result = (float) Math.pow(val1, val2);
}
```

Or alternative (coded Math.pow by myself):

```
public void execOP(float val1, float val2) {
    int i = 0;
    result = val1;
    if (val2 < 0) {

        System.out.println("Not possible");
    } else if (val2 == 0) {
        result = 1;
    } else {
        while (i < val2 - 1) {
            result = result * val1;
            i++;
        }
    }
```

How can I add a negative exponential operation to on of those codes?

Example: 5^-2 = 1/5^2

Comment: Negating the negative exponent and taking the reciprocal of the answer? i.e. `1.0f/execOP(val1, -val2)`.

Comment: the negative exponent could be converted to positive exponent and then positive exponent operation could be applied. The [Negative Exponents](https://www.purplemath.com/modules/exponent2.htm) page on purple math details how to write negative exponents using positive exponents